# Can I create multiple write transactions on single SQLite connection?

Tags: sqlite, ado.net, database-connection

I should not have multiple connection to access SQLite database, since while writing in database it will provide error like `Database is locked`. so I created multiple transaction. But, it seems every time it returns the same transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have only one transaction per connection.

There is no mechanism with which you could get multiple write transactions at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have multiple write transaction at the same time with NHibernate. The trick is to set the isolation level to be ReadCommitted. The ability to set that value in SQLite can be seen in the code [here](https://github.com/OpenDataSpace/System.Data.SQLite/blob/master/System.Data.SQLite/SQLiteTransaction.cs). However, I should mention that I have not been very happy with the behavior. Two sessions with active transactions works fine as long as the first session doesn't **read** any data until the second session is closed.

I highlighted read there because I can save a new object to the database without an issue, but calling Get() or QueryOvery() causes an exception when the second session has Commit() called on the transaction. The issue I see is that the SQLiteConnection gets disposed and disposing of the transaction checks for the connection not being disposed. This may be an issue with NHibernate only as I have not tested with anything more generic.